# $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = n \cdot \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \implies f(x,y) = g(nx+y)$ for some differentiable function $g$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Does $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = n \cdot \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \implies f(x,y) = g(nx+y)$ for some differentiable function $g$?

I found the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771734/about-frac-partial-fx-y-partial-x-frac-partial-fx-y-partial-y) but it uses directional derivatives. Is there a more elementary way to do this?

**Can we do something like this:**

Consider some $(a,b)$ and the line $nx+y = na+b$ it belongs to. We will show that every $(x,y)$ on this line maps to the same real number. For brevity, let $na+b = c$.

Let $h(x) = U(x,c-nx)$. Then
\begin{align*}\frac{\partial U(x,y)}{\partial x} = n \cdot \frac{\partial U(x,y)}{\partial y} &\implies \frac{dh(x)}{dx} = n \cdot \frac{dh(x)}{dy} = n \cdot \frac{dh(x)}{d(c-nx)} = \frac{dh(x)}{dx} \cdot (-1)  
\\ &\implies h'(x) = 0
\end{align*}

This tells us that $h$ is constant as desired.

**Is this proof correct?**

Comment: Please Let me know, if you got the answer , Really Interesting!!!

Comment: To find a solution you can use [the method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). The [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example) they used is exactly your problem.

Comment: The post now contains a proof. Is that correct?

Comment: if $h(x) = U(x, c - n x)$ then, bu the chain rule, :
$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}h}{\mathrm{d}x} (x) = \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial x}(x, c - n x) - n \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial y}(x, c - n x) = 0$$

Comment: @Essaidi Yes, and that proves $h$ is a constant.

Comment: Yes, $h$ is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will staudy the case $n \geq 2$. Let $(u, v) = (x + y, n x + y)$ and :
$$f(x, y) = g(u, v)$$
By the chain rule :

1. $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v} \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u} + n \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}$
2. $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v} \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u} +  \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}$

We have :
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = n \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$
then :
$$\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u} + n \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v} = n \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u} + n \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}$$ 
We deduce that :
$$\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u} = n \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u}$$ 
and because $n \geq 2$ :
$$\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u} = 0$$
$g$ is then a function of $v$ only :
$$g(u, v) = h(v)$$
which means :
$$f(x, y) = g(u, v) = h(v) = h(n x + y)$$

Comment: for the case $n = 1$ put :
$$(u, v) = (x + y, x- y)$$

Comment: Nice, Sir it's really interesting the transformation you attempt. But how you know that $f(x,y)=g(u,v)$

Comment: Okay got it thanks , and nice really nice

Comment: What is $g$ and how do you construct it? I don't get that part.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus it doesn't matter what $g$ actually is, what matters is that $g(u,v)$ returns the same values as $f(x,y)$ when $u=x+y$ and $v=nx+y$.

Comment: @Essaidi you should add the $n=1$ to your answer

Comment: @VictorSouza Thank you. I also added a proof in the post. Is that correct?